# Sending an image from javascript to php

Tags: javascript, php

## Original post

I want to use javascript to send some images to my Server running PHP, which then saves these images. I have followed [this guide](https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-upload-files-to-a-server-with-plain-javascript-and-php/), but my php script only recieves empty files.

I suspect that this piece of javascript from the guide:

```js
const files = document.querySelector('[type=file]').files;
const formData = new FormData();

for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  let file = files[i];
  formData.append('files[]', file);
}
```

does not really put the whole image data into `formData`. How can I fix this?

## Source code

PHP script:

```php
<?php
echo "Hello world";

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    var_dump($_FILES);
    $uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
    } else {
        echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
    }
}
?>
```

Javascript:

```
const url = "http://localhost:8888/post.php"
const files = document.querySelector('[type=file]').files;
const formData = new FormData();

for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    let file = files[i];
    formData.append('files[]', file);
}

console.log(files);

fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
}).then(response => {
    response.text().then((text) => {console.log(text)});
});
```

Output of the javascript:

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you share your form html?

Comment: Please attach the full source code that pertains to the upload logic. Also, have you tried submitting a form directly to your PHP script?

Comment: what happen to formData after, is it send by ajax or just $.post

Comment: _does not really put the whole image data into formData_ How do you know? Where is the PHP code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without actually seeing all of the code, it's hard to pinpoint any specific issue. If I follow the guide you linked to, I'm able to see the image posted to my server. This is my source code:

**process.php:**

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <?php
    var_dump($_POST);
    var_dump($_FILES);
  ?>
  <form>
    <input type="file">
  <input type="submit">
  </form>

  <script>
  const url = 'process.php'
  const form = document.querySelector('form')

  form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault()

    const files = document.querySelector('[type=file]').files
    const formData = new FormData()

    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      let file = files[i]

      formData.append('files[]', file)
    }

    fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
    }).then(response => {
      console.log(response)
    })
  })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In your case, I would recommend removing the javascript, setting the `action` attribute of your form to `process.php`, adding the `enctype` attribute to the form, setting it to `multipart/form-data`, and submitting an image that way. If you still don't see any images, then your issue may lie with PHP's configuration.

Your uploaded file may be too large. The default PHP max is 2MB. Try increasing the configuration value for `upload_max_filesize`. Also, if you increase the value of `upload_max_filesize`, you'll need to increase `post_max_size` too.

Here I a link to some common pitfalls: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php